# componentWillReceiveProps is not working in my react application. It's showing as undefined

Tags: reactjs

I have created a componentWillReceiveProps but it's working as expected.

It's throwing **Cannot read property '0' of undefined**

Is there a way to bypass this check.

MyCode:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
        console.log(newProps);
        if (typeof newProps.usableShippingAddresses[0] !== undefined && this.state.flag == true ) {
            this.setState({
                selectedAddressId: newProps.usableShippingAddresses[0].addressId
            })
            this.setState({
                flag: false
            })
            this.props.displaySelectedShippingAddress(newProps.usableShippingAddresses[0].addressId);
        }
    }
```

Can anyone please help me to troubleshoot the code.

Comment: componentWillReceiveProps(prevProps, prevState) has been deprecated by react team, rather use componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) instead. Also the function does not receive new props, your new props will be found in this.props

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to get the first element of a variable that does not exist (usableShippingAddresses). Also, if the `typeof` of something is undefined, it's noted as `'undefined'` and not `undefined` (as a string).

Try:

`if (typeof newProps.usableShippingAddress !== 'undefined' && newProps.usableShippingAddress.length > 0 && this.state.flag) {
  // do something with newProps.usableShippingAddress[0]
}`

`typeof newProps.usableShippingAddress !== 'undefined'` checks if the property exists at all.

`newProps.usableShippingAddress.length > 0` checks if it's iterable and isn't an empty array.

**Note** that your error doesn't have anything to do with the componentDidReceiveProps lifecycle - in fact, [it will be deprecated at React 17.](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops) in favor of componentDidUpdate.

Another tip is to avoid doing more than one `setState` behind eachother, you could combine your two setState's in one in this case.